# Can we see helpful flags rating?

Tags: discussion

I know [reputation rating](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/9/alltime/webmasters) exists but I would like to know if we can see users rating for helpful flags (if so, for Pro Webmasters and All Time). I'm just curious.

Comment: Don't think you can and I believe this is most likely intended by the main people at Stack for one reason or another as I'm sure they wouldn't overlook such a easy thing to add, but I could be wrong and wouldn't be the first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That feature has been explicitly removed for most "normal" users. There's a helpful/declined flag metric that is visible to mods and to oneself, but otherwise that information is generally kept low-visibility to prevent prejudicial actions against a user and to limit improper incentives.

There used to be a "flag weight" value which is no longer made clear to users *or* moderators.

Comment: Thanks Aarthi for your answer.

Comment: @Zistoloen My pleasure! Let me know if you need anything clarified. :)

Comment: All is clear thanks.